# In Spring how do I configure java.util.Logging so it can be autowired?

Tags: spring, tomcat, logging, autowired, java.util.logging

In our webapp we're using java.util.Logging (JULI, actually, since we deploy to Tomcat 6).  Logging is configured by a logging.properties file in WEB-INF/classes, a la [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html).

I'd like to configure the logger so it can be autowired, something like:

```
@Autowired
private Logger mylogger;
```

I've searched the Spring forums, the web, and of course Stack Overflow and I can't find how to set this up.  I'd appreciate any help on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to use the [Java Config style](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java), so you'd have one bean like this:

```
@Configuration
public class LoggerProvider {
    @Bean
    public Logger logger() {
        return Logger.getLogger("foobar.whatever");
    }
}
```

That could then be autowired into the rest of the app as normal.

Comment: Thanks - that was straightforward and easy to implement.  @Configuration requires cglib (I used cglib-nodep-2.2.jar) but that was my only difficulty.

Comment: @Paul: That's good to know. (I have cglib anyway because I'm doing complicated AOP in my app.)

Answer (score 2):

In order to use @Autowired on something (a bean) you must make that bean spring-controlled. There are many ways to do this and they depend on the logging framework you want to use.

I'm afraid there isn't a 'one-size-fits-all' solution.

Usually, you would use a static initializer provided by the logging framework of your choice or some abstraction over it (e.g. commons-logging).

I found one reference in which a @Logger annotation is introduced, maybe that points you into a direction of your liking:

http://jgeeks.blogspot.com/2008/10/auto-injection-of-logger-into-spring.html

Comment: Thanks but I found it more straightforward to use the accepted answer.  I didn't see the benefit in creating my own annotation over using the existing @Autowired.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make Logger be injectable with `@Autowired`, you must have a configuration class where you have configured all the Beans with which you use `@Autowired`. That class will be marked with `@Configuration`. There you must put the following `@Bean` in your configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public Logger produceLogger(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        Class<?> classOnWired = injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass();
        return LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOnWired);
    }
}
```